# Bootstrap glyphicons are displaying wrong images

Tags: ios, css, windows, bootstrap-modal, glyphicons

Downloaded bootstrap 3.3.7 and extracted all files which includes css, fonts and js folder. I copied all the files to www/css folder, www/js and www/css/fonts 
In index.html as below:

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and to use icons on button:

```
`<button type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>Yeah</button>
     <button type="button">span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Nope</button>
`
```

where icons not displayed properly chinese characters on android platform, other fancy icons are displaying on iOS platform and neither icons are showing for windows platform.

I tried to download from `npm install bootstrap` 
which is adding the folders to node_modules only and any approach not working.
Reason to not use the

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
```

because  application should work in offline so putting  files in project structure.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: include css of glyphicons also

Comment: There's no css of glyohicons may i know which css you reffered ? @maddy23285

Comment: open up the browsers dev tools and check if the font is loaded

Comment: @VilleKoo : not worked.. asking where is wrong in my hierarchy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for these lines in bootstrap.css and rectify the path to fonts folder accrodingly:

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: as I can see in question your bootstrap.css file is in under css folder and fonts folder is also under css folder. So your path to fonts folder should be src: url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');.

Comment: @AndroidGeeks learn how to use the dev tools and it will save you from trouble like this :)

Comment: @VilleKoo: the hierachy mistake dev tools don't suggest it is in css

Answer (score 0):

remove the www folder and put the folders(css/js/fonts) with your html code as its the common hierarchy of bootstrap

Comment: i mean the picture of whole file structure you have created